# Where to store release notes in Java projects that use a Gradle-Git-Artifactory stack

Tags: git, gradle, release, artifactory, gradle-release-plugin

I have several inter-dependent Java projects, all of which use **Git** for source control, **Gradle** for builds and releases, and **Artifactory** as a binary repository. The projects are all internal, used only within the company.

What's a good place to store the release notes for them? Our current notes are all over the place - some in git commits and tags, some in various text files. There has to be a better way.

Ideally, I'd like something that can be added as a simple step to a Gradle release task. And I'd like the notes of all the various versions to be easily accessible (without scrolling through the git commit history for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about using a changelog for those ?

Great reference is [keepachangelog](http://keepachangelog.com/) and I've just opened an [issue](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release/issues/151) to consider its support in [gradle-release-plugin](/questions/tagged/gradle-release-plugin):